# Splitting a string in to 2 separate strings

Tags: c#

I have the following string

string test = "f10";

What I want to do is seperate the test string into 2 separate strings.  For example string1 = "f" and string2 = "10".  How do I do this.  Do I use the string.split?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is based upon upon how many characters your string contains.

```
string test = "f10";
string s1 = str.Substring(0,1);
string s2= str.Substring(1,str.Length-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex if you want to get number and alphabet separately,

```
 string test = "f10";
 Regex re = new Regex(@"([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)");
 Match result = re.Match(test);
 string alphaPart = result.Groups[1].Value;
 string numberPart = result.Groups[2].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative getting alpha and numeric something like:

> using System.Linq;

```
var alpha = new String(input.Where(Char.IsLetter).ToArray());
var number = new String(input.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use String.Substring(start index, length).
Start index begins from 0.

```
string test = "f10";    
string1 = test.Substring(0, 1);
string2 = test.Substring(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what exactly you want to split by. If it is by the space between non-digit and digit:

```
string[] result = Regex.Split("f10", @"(?<=\D)(?=\d)");     // { "f", "10" }
```